# For each loop in Wordpress: content not returning

Tags: php, wordpress

I have queried the wordpress loop and try to return the post data in a foreach loop so I can get the first item and style it differently. However, the data returns the post ID in the foreach loop. However I can't seem to get the content. Can someone help?

```
<div class="tab-content">
<?php  
        $args = array(  'child_of' => $post->ID,  'parent ' => $post->ID, 'hierarchical' => 0, 
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'sort_order' => 'asc' );

        $mypages = get_pages( $args );

        $first = true; 

        foreach( $mypages as $page ) {

            $content = $page->post_content;
            $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );

              if ( $first )
              {
                // do something
                $first = false; //in order not to get into the if statement for the next loops 
                ?>
                    <div id="<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                     <?php echo $content; ?>
                   </div>
              <?php
              }
              else
              {
                // do something else for all loops except the first
                ?>
                   <div id="<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" class="tab-pane fade">
                     <?php echo $content; ?>
                   </div>
               <?php  
              }
        }

?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$content = $page->post_content;`

Should in fact be:

`$content = $post->post_content;`

And actually, assigning that to a variable `$content` doesn't really gain you anything. You could just use `echo $post->post_content;` instead.

Comment: Ok, cool -- you can update your code so the typo doesn't confuse other viewers with similar problems. Also, right after the `$mypages = get_pages( $args );` line, try putting `var_dump($mypages);` and see if you get anything. It's tough to say where the breakdown is without debugging a few things.

Comment: What did the var_dump output?

Answer (score 0):

Your $content = $page->post_content; should say $content = **$post**->post_content

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo however it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. Sorry I was having a server error which was cleared. So the query worked fine.